# PDO variable is part of a table name

Tags: php, pdo, parameters, binding, tablename

i am trying to bind a variable which is part of a table name when using PDO binding to prevent SQL injection.

my query is similar to this:

```
    select * from user_:id_user.kb_:id_kbase "."_frequencies"
```

which must result into

```
    select * from user_1.kb_123_frequency
```

where `user_1.kb_123_frequency` is the intended table name. However, when the parameters get bound in:

```
    $st->bindParam(':id_user', $id_user, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sth->bindParam(':id_kbase', $id_kbase, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sth->execute();
```

it fails to bind and throws the bellow error:

Exception has occurred.

```
Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: :id_kbase
```

i believe this is because of me trying to concatenate "`kb_:id_kbase`" with  "`_frequencies`" but `:kb_kbase` is a parameter.

so my question is: can you pass a table name as a parameter and if so How to do the binding when a parameter is part of a table name?

your help is much appreciated

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Prepared statements do not work that way.

The best (safest) way to do this, is to only accept a certain set of values, for example using a `switch` statement.

```
switch ($tbl) {
    case "baz":
    case "foo":
        $tbl = "bar".$tbl;
        break;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your quick response, i took your suggestion and this seems the best and safest solution